# Festival C/C++ API compiling an example, linking libraries error

Tags: c++, api, text-to-speech, festival

I am having problems with the festival C++ API (Windows XP).

After I make both festival and speech_tools succesfully (Cygwin), I have a file, called festival_example.cc, which contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <festival.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    EST_Wave wave;
    int heap_size = 210000;  // default scheme heap size
    int load_init_files = 1; // we want the festival init files loaded

    festival_initialize(load_init_files,heap_size);

    // Say simple file
    //festival_say_file("/etc/motd");

    festival_eval_command("(voice_ked_diphone)");
    // Say some text;
    festival_say_text("hello world");

    // Convert to a waveform
    festival_text_to_wave("hello world",wave);
    wave.save("/tmp/wave.wav","riff");

    // festival_say_file puts the system in async mode so we better
    // wait for the spooler to reach the last waveform before exiting
    // This isn't necessary if only festival_say_text is being used (and
    // your own wave playing stuff)
    festival_wait_for_spooler();

    return 0;
}
```

Then (Cygwin) I type:

```
g++ festival_example.cc -I./festival/src/include  -I./speech_tools/include -L./festival/src/lib -libFestival -L./speech_tools/lib -libestools -libestbase -libeststring
```

It cannot find the libraries. 
If I write -I/cygdrive/c/0621/source/build/festival/src/include and the same in all, the error persists.

I have my program in

C:\0621\source\build

And inside I have the folders \festival\ and \speech_tools\

:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846858/how-to-link-festival-tts-libraries-in-a-c-programme-using-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace -lib* with -l*.
For instance -libFestival won't work. Do

```
g++ festival_example.cc -I./festival/src/include  -I./speech_tools/include -L./festival/src/lib -lFestival
```

Comment: Thanks it works. However now I have new errors!

A lot of undefinded references... _tgetstr...etc.

Inside libFestival.a and libestools.a. Ideas?